# Function which shows tooltip on error and hides it on keypress

Tags: jquery, events, tooltip

I can't figure out how to create this simple function without bugs. I don't really care what tooltip plugin I use, I tried 4 of them and I was not succesful in this with any of them. I want it to just work properly. I need it for validation purposes, so when user makes mistake, it will let him know immediately what he does wrong. When I try to create it, it either:

- doesn't show at all
- shows just for a moment
- shows once and never hides
- shows once, hides once and never reappear again

I have trouble either with conflicting keydown/keypress, destroying tooltip etc.

My try with jquery plugin tooltipster:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
```

JS:

```
jQuery.fn.tooltipError =
function(error)
{
    return this.each(function(e)
    {
        var t = $(this);
        t.tooltipster({ content: error, toggle: 'custom'});
        $(window).on('keyup',function() {
            // t.tooltipster('hide');
            t.tooltipster('destroy');
        });
        t.tooltipster('show');
    });
};

$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.key == 'a')
    {
        $(this).tooltipError('Char "a" not allowed');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o946zb2b/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you're only showing the tooltip when it's not already shown and only destroying it if it exsits. You also should not fire the `keyup` event when the pressed key is the one that triggered the tooltip in the first place. This will handle it:

```
jQuery.fn.tooltipError =
function(error, isError)
{
    return this.each(function(e)
    {
        var t = $(this);
        if (!isError && t.hasClass("tooltipstered"))
            t.tooltipster("destroy");

        if (isError && !t.hasClass("tooltipstered"))
        {
            t.tooltipster({ content: error, toggle: "custom"});
            t.tooltipster("show");
        }
    });
};

$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.key == "a")
        e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tooltipError('Char "a" not allowed', e.key == "a");
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/o946zb2b/9/)**

EDIT: Updated the answer to remove double check and fix Fiddle link. Also, no warnings like this:

```
Tooltipster: one or more tooltips are already attached to this element: ignoring. Use the "multiple" option to attach more tooltips.
```

will be logged in the console when typing the `a` multiple times in a row.

EDIT 2: Updated the answer to destroy the tooltip in the function itself.

Comment: You put condition when to show/not show error twice - one inside the function, one outside the function. This is big no-no. I obviously want the ability to reuse this function later for other conditions. Plus, your fiddle link is wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer and Fiddle link.

Comment: Yes this works, but there is same problem as in another answer - a function is supposed to handle disappearing of tooltip.

Comment: Updated the answer to let the function handle the destroying of the tooltip.

Comment: You are awesome! I would never figure out using isError. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Existing problem is relatively straightforward. You are binding to a keyup while the key is down. It will fire as soon as you release the key

I would suggest using a short delay before binding the new handler, and importantly , removing it also

```
jQuery.fn.tooltipError = function (error) {
    return this.each(function (e) {
        var t = $(this);
        t.tooltipster({
            content: error,
            toggle: 'custom'
        });
        setTimeout(function () { /* short delay before iniitializing handler*/
            $(window).on('keydown.tooltip', function () {                    
                t.tooltipster('destroy');
                $(window).off('keydown.tooltip');/* remove handler*/
            });
        }, 10);
        t.tooltipster('show');
    });
};
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o946zb2b/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: This is closest to working, but if you press "a" twice, it crashes and does not reappear again

Comment: I solved this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/o946zb2b/8/ now just need figure out how not to hide it between keypreses when user types "a" twice

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to check if the object is initialized like:

```
jQuery.fn.tooltipError =
function(error, event, invalids)
{
   return this.each(function(e)
    {
       var t = $(this);
       var key = event.keyCode || e.which;
       if($.inArray(key,invalids) !== -1){
         t.tooltipster({ content: error, toggle: 'custom'});
          t.tooltipster('show');
          event.preventDefault();
         //t.val(t.substring(0,t.length -1));
      }else{
         if($(t).hasClass('tooltipstered')){
             $(t).tooltipster('destroy');
         }
      }
     //  return t;
   });
};

$('input').keydown(function(e) {

    var invalids = [65,66]; //Array as 65=A, 66=B
    $(this).tooltipError('Char "' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '" not allowed', e, invalids);


});
```

Please see **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o946zb2b/12/)**

Comment: This works same as my example = appears and right then disappears. I want it to disappear when user keypresses something else.

Comment: @gadelat Answer and fiddle updated. Please have a look.

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I want, but I would like the function to be reusable. You put code for destroying tooltip outside the function. I need the function to handle this by itself.  And that's the challenge of this question -  how to solve keydown conflict

Comment: @gadelat I have updated the answer and fiddle. Let me do some clarification here, they way you were doing is not possible because the function is already executed. You have to call it again if you want it within the function. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Now I can not type anything to inputbox

Comment: @gadelat sorry my bad. I have updated it again. Should be fine now.

Comment: Yeah, well now you put condition inside function. Point of this function is that I can call it when input is not valid. And condition when it's not valid should be outside of the func. See accepted answer. Even accepted answer is not ideal as it passes condition to func and that is kind of circumvention, but it does what needs to be done. If you can figure out how to do this without passing condition to func, I will change my accepted answer to yours. Cheers.

Comment: @gadelat I have made it more flexible now. please look